# How to click on web-element button without ID?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, automation

I need to click on the button but something goes wrong. Error raise "Object doesn't support this property or method" I have used this code

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.navigate "http://www.spark-interfax.ru/system/home/card#/company/3411D127F25A45F7ABAB32964A32848D/427"

ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("button-icon right-offset-5 sp-i-xls-download-grey").Click
End Sub
```

On web-page this button is shown as this code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm js-not-print"><i class="button-icon right-offset-5 sp-i-xls-download-grey"></i><span>Excel</span></button>
```

Comment: Button has class="btn btn-default btn-sm js-not-print" - I may not work or you may use properties like firstElementChild, nextElementSibling, previousElementSibling, etc. to get to proper element, also tagName can help identify if it is right one.

Comment: You probably want to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if you are wanting to get by multiple classes (if that is js?)

Comment: Is this post login? And what do you mean by _something goes wrong_ ?

Comment: It's button for downloading file

Comment: Error raised "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you are attempting to invoke a method of a single node on a collection.

This

```
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default btn-sm js-not-print")
```

returns a collection. Note: I changed the class name but principle remains.

You would need to index into the collection to get the right node e.g.

```
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default btn-sm js-not-print")(0).Click
```

If it is the first node you need to match you could try querySelector

```
ie.document.querySelector(".btn.btn-default.btn-sm.js-not-print").click
```

and ideally see if you can remove some of the compound class values (the class attribute is multi-valued i.e. more than one value -seperated by spaces in source) e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector(".btn.js-not-print").click
```